# Объединение логике нескольких проектов

Tags: angular, архитектура

У меня есть 3 проекта `angular` написанных на разных версиях `12,14,17`. Пока их 3 но потом может быть и больше. В них очень много всего одинакового (сервис авторизации, конфигурации, печати, логика ui таблиц, полей, модалок и т.д)

Проблема такая. Если в одном проекте делаются изменения в каком-либо месте глобально (например в общее отображение справочников добавляю логику, которая будет говорить что данное поле нельзя сортировать) или находится баг - то приходится менять во всех проектах, что есть не удобно.

Что пробовал.
Пробовал вынести общую логику в проект с монорепозиторием `nx` в качестве библиотек. Но столкнулся с проблемой. Если модели и функции вынеслись корректно (т. к. у них в зависимостях только `ts` и они корректно собираются и используются в нескольких версиях angular - то модули и сервисы должны собираться как внгуляр библиотеки (у nx есть установка и поддержка) и в итоге я снова привязываюсь к версии, т к `nx` должен как-то собрать.

Хотелось бы получить на выходе что-вроде такого:
npm/organization пакеты

```
@my-org/core (без публикации для общей логики для всех версий)
@my-org/core@12 (т.к. сервисы и модули желательно собрать под версию)
@my-org/core@14
@my-org/core@17
@my-org/functions
@my-org/models
@my-org/ui (без публикации для общей логики для всех версий)
@my-org/ui@12
@my-org/ui@14
@my-org/ui@17
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что бы вы посоветовали по организации чтобы получить желаемое.

Comment: А насколько сложно поднять версии для остальных приложений до 17? Возможно, что поднятие версий до 17 в двух приложениях будет равносильно танцам с бубнами для настройки билда 3-х версий одного и того же пакета

Comment: Возможно еще деплой вести из 2-х веток, v14 и v17. Будет ветка master, в которой исправляется баг, потом master мержится в v14-ветку и в v17-ветку, а потом из каждой деплой. Можно деплой как-то привязать к имени ветки, чтобы один деплой был, но от имя ветки как переменная добавлялась бы префиксом в имя библиотеки

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin поднять версии очень сложно, т к юзается зависмсимая от версии ui либа. И при поднятии с 14 версии выше там поменяли структуру html компонентов - и ситили прописанные к ним не работают, что есть очень проблемно, т.к. 2 проекта большие (они писались по 2 года каждый)

Comment: Я бы наверное сделал бы как описал выше тогда. Вносить доработки в master-ветку, из нее вливать изменения в ветки, которые связаны с версиями Angular. И потом деплоил из них уже. Но скажу сразу, вариант, скорее всего не самый идеальный. Можно посмотреть в сторону того, как поддерживают 2 мажорные версии, например, когда выпустили новую версию, но в старой еще правят баги, при этом баг может быть в обеих версиях.